# Undefined Ext for ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

New to ExtJs. I have looked at a bunch of threads, but everything I try is not working.  I am using ExtJS 4 and  I keep getting and undefined Ext error for the following code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

//app.js
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Hello Ext',
                    html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: please use your web browser's debugger to double-check that it's able to load /extjs/ext-all.js

Answer (score 3):

Check the path of ext-all.js. Make sure the first slash is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser failed to load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Which is next to certain to be a path issue. Thus the following line:

```
Ext.application({
```

Will raise the error you see (as there's no object `Ext` in scope).

> **Note that the path to the extjs library is relative to your index.html path**

So if `extjs` is a subfolder of the folder where index.html exists. You should really include it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ext-all.js path is correct than try

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if problem occure only in IE then  just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for upload latest javascript in IE